# WideImage - The loaded image does not store in an another variable if destroy method is called on original variable

Tags: php, wideimage

If the image's width and height is less than 400px then don't resize and save the $original in $resized. But if I call `$original->destroy()`, the data stored in `$resized` also gets `null`. How to destroy the original and keep its copy in `$resized` variable?

```
        $original = WideImage::loadFromFile($media_url);
        $original_w = $original->getWidth();
        $original_h = $original->getHeight();

        if($original_w > 400)
            $resized = $original->resize(400, null);
        elseif($original_w > 400 && $original_h > 400)
            $resized = $original->resize(null, 400);
        elseif($original_w < 400 && $original_h > 400)
            $resized = $original->resize(null, 400);
        else
            $resized = $original;
        $original->destroy();
        $img = WideImage::createTrueColorImage($resized->getWidth(), $resized->getHeight());
        $bg  = $img->allocateColor(255,255,255);
        $img->fill(0,0,$bg);


        $img->merge($resized)->saveToFile(sprintf('./uploads/photos/%s_resized.jpg', $rand_str));
```